# Cannot getContext on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, pdf.js

calling `canvas.getContext('2d);` give an error that canvas is undefined

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('sbspdfviewer');
canvas.getContext('2d');
```

I can see that the canvas object is my canvas object that I defined

but when I call `getContext('2d')` I get canvas is undefined.. All examples I see show I'm doing this correct..

The canvas tag is buried within some div tags.. but it's the only canvas tag on the page
This is where the canvas tag is

```
<div id="pdfcontainer" class="collapse collapsed">
   <div  class="panel panel-primary">
     <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Document Review</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="pdfviewcontainer" class="row" >
            <div class="col-lg-8 border">
                    <canvas id="sbspdfviewer" style="width: 100%"></canvas>
             </div>
             <div id="codes" class="col-lg-4 border">
                    <div class="padding"></div>
                    <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                            id="patientdocumentcodestable" style="width: 100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Preferred Text</th>
                                    <th>Node</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
canvas: canvas#sbspdfviewer
accessKey: ""
assignedSlot: null
attributeStyleMap: StylePropertyMap {size: 1}
attributes: NamedNodeMap {0: id, 1: style, id: id, style: style, length: 2}
autocapitalize: ""
baseURI: "http://localhost:8080/invenio/gui/findpatients.jsp"
childElementCount: 0
childNodes: NodeList []
children: HTMLCollection []
classList: DOMTokenList [value: ""]
className: ""
clientHeight: 0
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 0
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap {}
dir: ""
draggable: false
firstChild: null
firstElementChild: null
height: 150
hidden: false
id: "sbspdfviewer"
innerHTML: ""
innerText: ""
inputMode: ""
isConnected: true
isContentEditable: false
lang: ""
lastChild: null
lastElementChild: null
localName: "canvas"
namespaceURI: "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
nextElementSibling: null
nextSibling: text
nodeName: "CANVAS"
nodeType: 1
nodeValue: null
nonce: ""
offsetHeight: 0
offsetLeft: 0
offsetParent: null
offsetTop: 0
offsetWidth: 0
onabort: null
onauxclick: null
onbeforecopy: null
onbeforecut: null
onbeforepaste: null
onblur: null
oncancel: null
oncanplay: null
oncanplaythrough: null
onchange: null
onclick: null
onclose: null
oncontextmenu: null
oncopy: null
oncuechange: null
oncut: null
ondblclick: null
ondrag: null
ondragend: null
ondragenter: null
ondragleave: null
ondragover: null
ondragstart: null
ondrop: null
ondurationchange: null
onemptied: null
onended: null
onerror: null
onfocus: null
onfullscreenchange: null
onfullscreenerror: null
ongotpointercapture: null
oninput: null
oninvalid: null
onkeydown: null
onkeypress: null
onkeyup: null
onload: null
onloadeddata: null
onloadedmetadata: null
onloadstart: null
onlostpointercapture: null
onmousedown: null
onmouseenter: null
onmouseleave: null
onmousemove: null
onmouseout: null
onmouseover: null
onmouseup: null
onmousewheel: null
onpaste: null
onpause: null
onplay: null
onplaying: null
onpointercancel: null
onpointerdown: null
onpointerenter: null
onpointerleave: null
onpointermove: null
onpointerout: null
onpointerover: null
onpointerup: null
onprogress: null
onratechange: null
onreset: null
onresize: null
onscroll: null
onsearch: null
onseeked: null
onseeking: null
onselect: null
onselectionchange: null
onselectstart: null
onstalled: null
onsubmit: null
onsuspend: null
ontimeupdate: null
ontoggle: null
onvolumechange: null
onwaiting: null
onwebkitfullscreenchange: null
onwebkitfullscreenerror: null
onwheel: null
outerHTML: "<canvas id="sbspdfviewer" style="width: 100%"></canvas>"
outerText: ""
ownerDocument: document
parentElement: div.col-lg-8.border
parentNode: div.col-lg-8.border
part: DOMTokenList [value: ""]
prefix: null
previousElementSibling: null
previousSibling: text
scrollHeight: 0
scrollLeft: 0
scrollTop: 0
scrollWidth: 0
shadowRoot: null
slot: ""
spellcheck: true
style: CSSStyleDeclaration {0: "width", alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", all: "", …}
tabIndex: -1
tagName: "CANVAS"
textContent: ""
title: ""
translate: true
width: 300
__proto__: HTMLCanvasElement
```

Comment: Show us. Othewise we have to guess.

Comment: for instance, How do you do this: _I can see that the canvas object is my canvas object that I defined_

Comment: looking in the debugger I can see that the element is the canvas element I defined

Comment: We really need to see the code, specifically what wraps `canvas.getContext('2d);`

Comment: Your code works just fine https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XwLpdX . Maybe you didn't link the js file, execute js before html is rendered, or didn't write the canvas id right.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide a code to check the error, so I will suggest two things based on the error message which is undefined:

1. The id is wrong either in JS code or in HTML tag.
2. The Javascript file is not linked to the HTML file correctly

check them and read the canvas documentation and check examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Basic_usage

Hope this is going to help you

Answer (score 0):

Works ok for me.
I suspect you may trying to get the canvas context before the page is fully loaded.
The code below shows one way of waiting until the page is loaded before trying to get the canvas.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('sbspdfviewer');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  console.log(context);
});
```

```html
<div id="pdfcontainer" class="collapse collapsed">
   <div  class="panel panel-primary">
     <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Document Review</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="pdfviewcontainer" class="row" >
            <div class="col-lg-8 border">
                    <canvas id="sbspdfviewer" style="width: 100%"></canvas>
             </div>
             <div id="codes" class="col-lg-4 border">
                    <div class="padding"></div>
                    <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
                            id="patientdocumentcodestable" style="width: 100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Preferred Text</th>
                                    <th>Node</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this was completely my own fault.. I misused the this keyword.. the canvas was defined as this.canvas= document.getElementById('myid') and I then did ctx = canvas.getContext('2d') instead of this.canvas.getContext('2d').

Sorry.. it's been a long day